# Failed to marshal EJB parameters?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, serializable, vaadin-flow, apache-commons-beanutils

I have added a new method to `EJB3` and I get the following error. I know it is due to serializable issue, but I can't change the object because it is from external library  `org.apache.commons.beanutils`.

Furthermore, I use Wildfly 11 as server and Vaadin 18 with java 8.

**Is there any workaround for it?**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYEJB0054: Failed to marshal EJB parameters
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:385)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:365)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver$CloningResultProducer.getResult(LocalEjbReceiver.java:304)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:567)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:118)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:78)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:172)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:907)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:165)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:100)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.findRecordsInTable(Unknown Source)
```

**EJB**

```
@Stateless
@Remote(QueriesRemote.class)
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public class Queries extends Base implements QueriesRemote{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;
    
    @Resource(mappedName="java:/TedingDS")
    private javax.sql.DataSource db;

    @Resource
    SessionContext ctx;
    

    
    public List<DynaBean> findRecordsInTable(String querySource){
        List<DynaBean> beanList = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

        try (ResultSet myResult = db.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).executeQuery(querySource)) {
            RowSetDynaClass rsdc = new RowSetDynaClass(myResult, false);
            beanList =  rsdc.getRows();
            closeAllViaResultSet(myResult);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "From class:".concat(this.getClass().getName()));
        }

        return beanList;
    }

}
```

**How I call it**

```
@Route(value = QueriesView.ROUTE, layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle(QueriesView.TITLE)
public class QueriesView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver, BeforeLeaveObserver, AfterNavigationObserver, LocaleChangeObserver, HasUrlParameter<String> {
    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    public static final String ROUTE = "queryView";
    public static final String TITLE = "Query";


        @EJB
        public QueriesRemote remote;

        public QueriesView() {}

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        LOGGER.info("beforeEnter queryView");
        if(remote == null)
            Notification.show("beforeEnter remote == null");
        else {
            List<DynaBean> list = remote.findRecordsInTable("select * from attached limit 5");
            Notification.show("Size beforeEnter:".concat(String.valueOf(list.size())), 5000, Notification.Position.MIDDLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are both the vaadin app and the EJB on the same server? If they are you could use a `@Local` interface instead of  `@Remote`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @areus

I just used `@Local` interface instead of `@Remote`